# Properties of sum of riemannian metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have a riemannian manifold $M$ and two metrics $g_1,g_2$. I was wondering what sort of properties will $g_1+g_2$ inherit from $g_1,g_2$. For example, if $g_i$ have positive injectivity radius then so will $g_1+g_2$?

Do any know of such properties that would be preserved. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I give examples [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2682383/39599) which demonstrate that if $g_1$, $g_2$ have non-negative/positive scalar curvature, $g_1 + g_2$ may not have non-negative/positive scalar curvature.

Comment: If you assume a metric to be sufficiently small in the $C^2$ norm relative to a metric with positive scalar, Ricci, or sectional curvature, then their sum will be the same. Otherwise, it would be difficult to get a result like this for scalar or Ricci. There’s a chance you could say something more if you assume the metrics have positive sectional curvature but I’d need to think about that.

Comment: @C.F.G OP did not ask about curvature. But your link is still relevant since the question is open-ended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few properties are preserved by the addition of Riemannian metrics $g_1, g_2$ on a manifold $M$:

1. Completeness.
2. Positivity of the injectivity radius.

The proofs in both cases are quite simple and follow from the trivial observation that
$$
g_1(v,v) + g_2(v,v) \ge g_1(v,v)
$$
for every vector $v\in TM$. Hence, for every path $c$ in $M$,
$$
\ell_{g_1+g_2}(c)\ge \ell_{g_1}(c),
$$
where $\ell$ is the length function.

3. Infiniteness of volume, due to the inequality
   $$
   \det(A+B)\ge \det(A) +\det(B)\ge \det(A) 
   $$
   for positive-definite matrices $A,B$.

In all these cases, it suffices to assume that one of the metrics satisfies the desired property, then $g_1+g_2$ also has it.

4. Also, trivially, if $g_1, g_2$ are Hermitian/Kahler for a common complex structure $J$, then so is $g_1+g_2$.

Other than that, I think nothing of interest is preserved.