# Scalar curvature of metrics combination

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed manifold. Suppose we have two metrics $g_1,g_2$, whose scalar curvatures are $scal_1$ and $scal_2$. Given a cut-off function $\rho$ supported near a point $x\in M$ with $0\leq\rho\leq1$, we have a combinative metric $\rho g_1+(1-\rho)g_2$, whose scalar curvature is denoted by $scal_{\rho}$.

**Q** Can we get some bound(s) of $scal_{\rho}$ in terms of $scal_1$, $scal_2$,  $\rho$ and $\nabla \rho$? (If we know that $c_1g_1\leq g_2\leq C_1g_1$, could this help to solve it?)

PS: I donot know if the question have been solved or not, so any reference is welcome.

Comment: If you take $\rho$ such that both $\rho$ and $1-\rho$ are positive functiuons, you can perhaps use the formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Conformal_change_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000005A-QINU%60%22'%7F) relating metrics transformed under conformal transformations to get the scalar curvature of both terms and take it up from there.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the meaning of  "take it up", do you mean "sum up"? @topolosaurus

Comment: I don't know how to compute the scalar curvature of a sum of metrics in terms of the scalar curvatures of the individual metrics. If there is a relation between them, it must be complicated. For example, the sum of positive (non-negative) scalar curvature metrics need not have positive (non-negative) scalar curvature, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2682383/39599).

Comment: To emphasis Michael Albanese's comment, the scalar curvature of a metric is a double trace of its Riemannian curvature tensor, which is defined in terms of commutators of the Levi-Civita connection. For two different metrics, I know no relation between their respective Levi-Civita connections and the Levi Civita connection of their sum. It looks like this is even worse for their scalar curvature